# Using a custom resnet18 code in PyTorch transfer learning

Tags: python, pytorch, python-import, attributeerror

I am using the resnet18 from this file https://gist.github.com/nikogamulin/7774e0e3988305a78fd73e1c4364aded and added the code into `custom_resnet18.py` as follows below:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class Block(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_layers, in_channels, out_channels, identity_downsample=None, stride=1):
        assert num_layers in [18, 34, 50, 101, 152], "should be a a valid architecture"
        super(Block, self).__init__()
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        if self.num_layers > 34:
            self.expansion = 4
        else:
            self.expansion = 1
        # ResNet50, 101, and 152 include additional layer of 1x1 kernels
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=1, stride=1, padding=0)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels)
        if self.num_layers > 34:
            self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(out_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, stride=stride, padding=1)
        else:
            # for ResNet18 and 34, connect input directly to (3x3) kernel (skip first (1x1))
            self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, stride=stride, padding=1)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(out_channels, out_channels * self.expansion, kernel_size=1, stride=1, padding=0)
        self.bn3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels * self.expansion)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.identity_downsample = identity_downsample

    def forward(self, x):
        identity = x
        if self.num_layers > 34:
            x = self.conv1(x)
            x = self.bn1(x)
            x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.bn2(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = self.bn3(x)

        if self.identity_downsample is not None:
            identity = self.identity_downsample(identity)

        x += identity
        x = self.relu(x)
        return x


class ResNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_layers, block, image_channels, num_classes):
        assert num_layers in [18, 34, 50, 101, 152], f'ResNet{num_layers}: Unknown architecture! Number of layers has ' \
                                                     f'to be 18, 34, 50, 101, or 152 '
        super(ResNet, self).__init__()
        if num_layers < 50:
            self.expansion = 1
        else:
            self.expansion = 4
        if num_layers == 18:
            layers = [2, 2, 2, 2]
        elif num_layers == 34 or num_layers == 50:
            layers = [3, 4, 6, 3]
        elif num_layers == 101:
            layers = [3, 4, 23, 3]
        else:
            layers = [3, 8, 36, 3]
        self.in_channels = 64
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(image_channels, 64, kernel_size=7, stride=2, padding=3)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.maxpool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)

        # ResNetLayers
        self.layer1 = self.make_layers(num_layers, block, layers[0], intermediate_channels=64, stride=1)
        self.layer2 = self.make_layers(num_layers, block, layers[1], intermediate_channels=128, stride=2)
        self.layer3 = self.make_layers(num_layers, block, layers[2], intermediate_channels=256, stride=2)
        self.layer4 = self.make_layers(num_layers, block, layers[3], intermediate_channels=512, stride=2)

        self.avgpool = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((1, 1))
        self.fc = nn.Linear(512 * self.expansion, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.bn1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.maxpool(x)

        x = self.layer1(x)
        x = self.layer2(x)
        x = self.layer3(x)
        x = self.layer4(x)

        x = self.avgpool(x)
        x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], -1)
        x = self.fc(x)
        return x

    def make_layers(self, num_layers, block, num_residual_blocks, intermediate_channels, stride):
        layers = []

        identity_downsample = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(self.in_channels, intermediate_channels*self.expansion, kernel_size=1, stride=stride),
                                            nn.BatchNorm2d(intermediate_channels*self.expansion))
        layers.append(block(num_layers, self.in_channels, intermediate_channels, identity_downsample, stride))
        self.in_channels = intermediate_channels * self.expansion # 256
        for i in range(num_residual_blocks - 1):
            layers.append(block(num_layers, self.in_channels, intermediate_channels)) # 256 -> 64, 64*4 (256) again
        return nn.Sequential(*layers)


def ResNet18(img_channels=3, num_classes=1000):
    return ResNet(18, Block, img_channels, num_classes)


def ResNet34(img_channels=3, num_classes=1000):
    return ResNet(34, Block, img_channels, num_classes)


def ResNet50(img_channels=3, num_classes=1000):
    return ResNet(50, Block, img_channels, num_classes)


def ResNet101(img_channels=3, num_classes=1000):
    return ResNet(101, Block, img_channels, num_classes)


def ResNet152(img_channels=3, num_classes=1000):
    return ResNet(152, Block, img_channels, num_classes)


def test():
    net = ResNet18(img_channels=3, num_classes=1000)
    y = net(torch.randn(4, 3, 224, 224)).to("cuda")
    print(y.size())
    
test()
```

and I am using this code in another file named `transfer_learning.ipynb` as follows in a code block:

```
# using the custom resnet18 
import custom_resnet18
model_ft = custom_resnet18.ResNet18()
num_ftrs = model_ft.fc.in_features
# Here the size of each output sample is set to 2.
# Alternatively, it can be generalized to nn.Linear(num_ftrs, len(class_names)).
model_ft.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 2)

model_ft = model_ft.to(device)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

# Observe that all parameters are being optimized
optimizer_ft = optim.SGD(model_ft.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

# Decay LR by a factor of 0.1 every 7 epochs
exp_lr_scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer_ft, step_size=7, gamma=0.1)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'custom_resnet18' has no attribute 'ResNet18'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_24784/1186722283.py in <module>
      1 # using the custom resnet18
      2 import custom_resnet18
----> 3 model_ft = custom_resnet18.ResNet18()
      4 num_ftrs = model_ft.fc.in_features
      5 # Here the size of each output sample is set to 2.

AttributeError: module 'custom_resnet18' has no attribute 'ResNet18'
```

How can I fix this error?
I have:

```
$ pip freeze
argon2-cffi==20.1.0
attrs==21.2.0
backcall==0.2.0
bleach==4.1.0
cffi==1.14.6
cycler==0.10.0
debugpy==1.4.1
decorator==5.0.9
defusedxml==0.7.1
entrypoints==0.3
h5py==3.3.0
ipykernel==6.2.0
ipython==7.26.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==7.6.3
jedi==0.18.0
Jinja2==3.0.1
joblib==1.0.1
jsonschema==3.2.0
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==7.0.1
jupyter-console==6.4.0
jupyter-core==4.7.1
jupyterlab-pygments==0.1.2
jupyterlab-widgets==1.0.0
kiwisolver==1.3.1
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
matplotlib==3.4.3
matplotlib-inline==0.1.2
mistune==0.8.4
nbclient==0.5.4
nbconvert==6.1.0
nbformat==5.1.3
nest-asyncio==1.5.1
notebook==6.4.3
numpy==1.21.2
packaging==21.0
pandocfilters==1.4.3
parso==0.8.2
pexpect==4.8.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==8.3.1
prometheus-client==0.11.0
prompt-toolkit==3.0.20
ptyprocess==0.7.0
pycparser==2.20
Pygments==2.10.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
pyrsistent==0.18.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pyzmq==22.2.1
qtconsole==5.1.1
QtPy==1.10.0
scikit-learn==0.24.2
scipy==1.7.1
Send2Trash==1.8.0
six==1.16.0
sklearn==0.0
terminado==0.11.1
testpath==0.5.0
threadpoolctl==2.2.0
torch==1.9.0
torchaudio==0.9.0
torchvision==0.10.0
tornado==6.1
traitlets==5.0.5
typing-extensions==3.10.0.0
wcwidth==0.2.5
webencodings==0.5.1
widgetsnbextension==3.5.1
```

Comment: What about the result of printing all attributes and methods of the module by `print(dir(custom_resnet))`

Answer (score 0):

Added the following before the erroneous cell in the Jupyter notebook. Restarting the `VSCode` or closing and opening the `ipynb` file didn't solve the problem. Note that I used `remote-ssh` extension for connecting to the remote host in `VSCode` through `VPN`:

```
import importlib
importlib.reload
```

[image]

Result of `print(dir(custom_resnet18))` before adding this cell:

```
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__']
```

and after adding this cell:

```
['Block', 'ResNet', 'ResNet101', 'ResNet152', 'ResNet18', 'ResNet34', 'ResNet50', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'nn', 'test', 'torch']
```

Answer credits to `jinsun`